# unable to store values in intermediate table laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Idea and community model. A Many to many relationship exists between them. Relationships are being formed perfectly. however, i am facing one issue. 
An idea can be found in may communities and a community can have many ideas. So, based on this there is an intermediate table. i am unable to store `community_id` and `idea_id` in pivot table.

```
public function storePost(IdeaRequest $request)
{
  if ($request->hasFile('idea_image')) {
      $filename = $request->file('idea_image')->getClientOriginalName();
      $moveImage = $request->file('idea_image')->move('images/', $filename);
  }
      $idea = new Idea();
      $idea->idea_title = $request->input('idea_title');
      $idea->user_id = Auth::id();
      $idea->idea_image = $moveImage;
      $idea->idea_info = $request->input('idea_info');
      $idea->communities()->attach($request->input('selection'));
      $idea->idea_location = $request->input('idea_location');
      $idea->idea_goal = $request->input('idea_goal');
      $idea->idea_description = strip_tags($request->input('idea_description'));
      $idea->save();
      Session::set('idea_id',$idea->id);
      session()->flash('flash_message', 'Your idea has been submitted for Review, Kindly Fill this Work BreakDown of You Work');
      return redirect()->route('create_wbs');
}
```

This line is making issue

> $idea->communities()->attach($request->input('selection'));

[image: cannot add/update]

**Edit:**

```
<form id="create_idea" class="clearfix" action="{{url('/idea')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

     <div class="form form-post-idea">
     <div class="left-input"><h3>Project Title:</h3></div>
     <label for="project_title"></label>
     <input type="text" name="idea_title" class="txt fill-width project_title" placeholder="Project Title"/>

     <label for="project_image"><h3>Project Image:</h3></label>
     <input type="file" name="idea_image" class="txt fill-width project_image" placeholder="Project Image" value=""/>

     <label for="project_info"><h3>Short Info of Project:</h3></label>
     <textarea name="idea_info" class="txt fill-width" placeholder="Info should not exceed 150 characters."></textarea>

     <label for="project_community"><h3>Project Community:</h3></label>
     <select class="txt fill-width project_community" name="selection[]" multiple>
        @foreach($Community as $selectCommunity)
          <option>{{$selectCommunity->community_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <label for="project_location"> <h3>Project Location:</h3></label>
    <input id="project_location" type="text" name="idea_location" class="txt fill-width idea_location" placeholder="Project Location" value=""/>

    <label for="funding_goal"><h3>Funding Goal:</h3></label>
    <input id="funding_goal" type="number" name="idea_goal" class="txt fill-width idea_goal" placeholder="Amout needed to complete Project" value=""/>

    <label for="project_description"><h3>Project Description:</h3></label>
    <textarea id="content" name="idea_description" class="txt fill-width" placeholder="Project Description"></textarea>
    <label for="submit_for_review"></label><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-green btn-buck-project" value="Submit For Review" id="review">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the relation in the line

```
 $idea->communities()->attach($request->input('selection'));
```

there is no idea_id to add to the pivot table because you haven't save the idea object to the database.You need before that to save it with all it's attributes and then add the relation.  Also as you can see in the query, you don't pass the community_id from your request but your community name which I think will also be a problem.

**Edit after update**

You should also pass the value of the community_id from your view.

```
@foreach($Community as $selectCommunity)
   <option value="{{$selectCommunity->community_id}}">{{$selectCommunity->community_name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: it means i should add the stated line after ` $idea->save();` then it would save the `idea_id`. if yes then its great, what should id do for storing `community_id` ?

Comment: Yes that 's correct.Are communities already exists? If yes community_id should be saved automatically if passed correctly from trom the $request.

Comment: yes `communities` already exists but its `id` is not storing its returning `community_name` instead which is causing an error.

Comment: You have to configure correctly your code in the view. Why don't you post the view code also? It's difficult to find out what is the problem without the view code

Comment: I have added the view code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks man! one more while it is storing values. the way foreign key is setup when a community is deleted `idea` should also be deleted. but it is not happening? `$table->foreign('community_id')->references('id')->on('communities')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115752/discussion-between-geoandri-and-qasim-ali).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is first save your Idea record and them, create an IdeaComunnity object, set the respective ID's (Idea and Community) and save this object.

Your error is occurring probably because your Idea object it's not yet saved, so, you have this constraint exception.